# storing images in PostgreSQL from java

Tags: java, android, postgresql

I'm working on an android app which is supposed to save an image on a PostgreSQL DB.
I'd like to know which are the best ways to do this. 
Is there a 'better' way to do this?
thx guys!

Comment: DB is runnng on adroid, or on server?

Comment: Db is running on server

Comment: Divide problem in two: how to transmit over network (webservice), how to store (look at @DimaSan comment)

Comment: mods: this is not exact duplicate, but agree, this is poor question